# Capistrano + Carrierwave issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, carrierwave

I have an issue with Carrierwave and Capistrano. The situation is:

- I have set Capistrano to keep only one release. (testing proposals).
- The current release is pointing to 20140918231215.
- Capistrano has the option:

  set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets tmp/sessions public/uploads}

So, current public/uploads is linked to shared/public/uploads, that's ok. The issue appears when I upload a new file. In this case a new folder is created in before release's folder.

Is there any way to refresh Capistrano Uploader store_dir, I suspect that is taking a bad configuration.

Notes:

- The new symlink from last_release to shared is correctly created.
- The before release is deleted correctly.
- The problem is that when I upload the new image, it is created in before_release/public/uploads. That folder doesn't exist, so It is created without symlink, obviously.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder in your server is properly symlinked, then capistrano is doing its work properly.

Your problem sounds for me that your uploader is doing the wrong thing.

Check the `store_dir` method, may be is doing something crazy:
Mine looks like this:

```
class LogoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Take into account that carrierwave already uses by default the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieve to write to the new folder (last release) by means of doing "sudo service nginx restart" after deploy, what I thought was unnecessary, it is?

EDIT:

I got it! I have added that line to config/deploy.rb:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Restart"
  task :restart do
    on roles(:web) do
      execute "touch #{release_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
    end
  end
end
```

I've also added the file restart.txt to tmp folder.

It seems the "trick" to restart Ruby on Rails via Phusion Passenger.